# SQL column doesn't exist on insert

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask application that is connected to a postgresql database. My issue is that when I query the database using SQLAlchemy to insert an item, this is what happens:

```py
from sqlalchemy import insert

catInfoString = json.dumps(catInfo)
productsString = json.dumps(products)

stmt = (
    insert(Category).
    values(catInfo=str(catInfoString), products=str(productsString))
)
```

I get this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "catInfo" of relation "category" does not exist`

So, I tried to see if catInfo exists with this:

```py
allCatInfo = db.engine.execute("SELECT catInfo FROM Category")
print(allCatInfo)
```

This worked perfectly. So why is it that I can query this table, but not insert?

### Variable outputs

`catInfoString`:
`{"name": "test", "shortDesc": "cat desc"}`

`productsString`:
`[["test", {"title": "holderProduct", "path": ["Products", "test"], "desc": "product desc"}]]`

`type(catInfoString)`:
`<class 'str'>`

`type(productsString)`:
`<class 'str'>`

### Case Sensitive

Also, when I try to use `catinfo` instead of `catInfo`, I get this error message:

`sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: catinfo`

### Using `INSERT INTO ...`

I tried using this line instead too...

```
qry = "INSERT INTO Category (catInfo, products) VALUES (%s, %s)" % (str(catInfoString), str(productsString))
db.engine.execute(qry)
```

However, this did not work either and raised the error below:
`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "{"`

Comment: The raw sql query you're using does not (double) quote `catInfo`. As such, postgresql interprets it as `catinfo` (unquoted identifiers are lowercased). My guess is that psycopg2 always double-quotes identifiers, so the query is looking for `"catInfo"`, which is not the same as `"catinfo"`. You can check this by running `db.engine.execute('SELECT "catInfo" FROM Category')` (which, if I'm right, should fail). My personal recommendation is to never use uppercase characters in database objects (at least when using postgresql), use snake_case instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive)

Comment: No unfortunately not @AdrianKlaver

Comment: @Marth I have updated the question with what you have requested.

Comment: Actually it does. I'm guessing if  you change `catInfo=str(catInfoString)` to `catinfo=str(catInfoString)` it will work.

Comment: Actually, that does not work... I have updated my question to show you what happens when I do that @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Then you are going to need to show how you define `Category`. There are two ways you get this error: 1) The case is not matching 2) The column does not actually exist in the table. You can get to 2) by pointing at the wrong database or the wrong instance of the table, think non-schema qualified table name and `search_path` picking the wrong table.

Comment: But that does not explain why the query: `SELECT catInfo from Category' works, but inserting into it doesnt... @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Because `SELECT catInfo FROM Category` will down case `catInfo` to `catinfo`. Reading the link I sent explains this. Obviously, the other SQLAlchemy method is preserving the case of `catInfo`.

Comment: Ok... that means that if I were to swap `catInfo` to `catinfo`, it would work as that is all the `select` is doing. So why does it not work when I do that. Alternatively, what if I used `INSERT INTO Category`...? @AdrianKlaver

Comment: As I said earlier you need to show how you define `Category`?

Comment: Please check the update @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245832/discussion-between-adrian-klaver-and-safnasfsa).

Comment: You could be missing the single quotes around your values in your SQL statement i.e `... VALUES ('%s', '%s')`